# I have a problems in showing data by using QueryBuilder

Tags: twig, symfony4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVLCk.png)My data cannot show!!!I am using query builder to show and filter data but when i call it in view page it not show. Am i doing wrong or something?

```
      /**
       * @Route("/search", name="searchEvent")
       */

    public functionnsearchAction(Request $request){
       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
       $queryBuilder = $em->getRepository(Event::class)- 
     >createQueryBuilder('e');

       if($request->query->getAlnum('filter')){
           $queryBuilder
              ->where('e.major LIKE :major')
              ->setParameter('major', '%' . $request->query- 
     >getAlnum('filter') . '%');
        }
        $event = $queryBuilder->getQuery();

        return $this->render('event/showEvent.html.twig',array(
           'event' => $event
        ));
```

Please help !I am new to symfony!
Here is my view code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVLCk.png)
view page[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2wV5.png)

Comment: Instead of pasting links, please edit the question and add your code.

Comment: yeh at the first i add my code but it says too much code and add more note. Im sorry about that. it's inconvenient =(

Comment: add minimum code and try to include some details about what you have tried and the issue you are facing. Thanks

Comment: did you verify `$event` actually contains data? Also your code is very confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently passing the query into your template, not the results of the query.

You will want to change the line `$event = $queryBuilder->getQuery();` into something like `$event = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();`.